# Can't get the text of a tag in HTML page

Tags: html, dom, dart

I'm trying to do web scraping to use with my application. I have a problem with getting one element in the HTML response I got.
for example, I have this element in the HTML:

```
<div class="cell card fr-news-box" style="flex-grow: 0;">
  <div class="card-section"><img src="https://fimgs.net/mdimg/perfume/m.53441.jpg"></div> 
  <div class="card-section">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Narciso-Rodriguez/Pure-Musc-For-Her-53441.html" target="_blank"> Pure Musc For Her<span class="link-span"></span></a>
    </p> 
    <p>
      <small>Narciso Rodriguez</small>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
<p><small>Narciso Rodriguez</small></p>
```

but nothing I tried work.
This is what I have so far:

```
  Future initiate() async{
  var client = Client();
  Response response = await client.get(
    'https://www.fragrantica.com/search/'
  );

  var document = parse(response.body);
  List<Element> perfumes = document.getElementsByClassName('cell card fr-news-box');

  List perfumeImg = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].attributes['src']).toList();
  List perfumeLink = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].attributes['href']).toList();
  List perfumeName = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].text).toList();

  List perfumeBrand = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('#main-content > div.grid-x.grid-margin-x > div.small-12.medium-8.large-9.cell > div > div > div > div.off-canvas-content.content1.has-reveal-left > div.grid-x.grid-padding-x.grid-padding-y > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > span > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(2) > small')[0].text).toList();
}
```

The problem is in the `perfumeBrand` line which crashes every time I try to run getting this error:

```
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)
```

I tried few other solutions but nothing works, I just can't get this `<p><small>XYZ</small></p> tag.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `querySelectorAll` to simplify your query.
But you cannot use ":nth-child" because of a [bug](https://github.com/dart-lang/html/issues/84) currently with the [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html) package.

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

main() {
  var document = parse(_body);
  var perfumes = document.querySelectorAll('.cell .card-section p');

  print(perfumes[1].outerHtml);
}

String _body = '''
<div class="cell card fr-news-box" style="flex-grow: 0;">
  <div class="card-section"><img src="https://fimgs.net/mdimg/perfume/m.53441.jpg"> 
</div> 
 <div class="card-section">
   <p>
     <a href="https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Narciso-Rodriguez/Pure-Musc-For-Her-53441.html" target="_blank"> Pure Musc For Her<span class="link-span"></span></a>
   </p> 
   <p>
     <small>Narciso Rodriguez</small>
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
''';
```